# Mysql InnoDB table to elasticsearch: ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP inside transaction

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I want to keep my MySQL database table in sync with the corresponding elasticsearch index. I'm trying to write my own cron job. MySQL table has the InnoDB engine. I added `updated_at` column that is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I use this query to perform sync:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE updated_at>=bookmark;
```

I tested it and found that some inserts had been lost.

Is CURRENT_TMESTAMP calculated before COMMIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` -- a synonym for `NOW()` -- captures its value at the beginning of execution of the query that invokes it.  These functions maintain a constant value regardless of how long the query runs -- so in cases such as long-running updates, all the affected rows will have the same value, and that value should be when each individual query started executing -- not commit time.

> `NOW()` returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger, `NOW()` returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for `SYSDATE()`, which returns the exact time at which it executes.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now